# Mega Menu Walker

Tags: php, functions, menus, navigation, walker

I'm trying to create a mega menu walker. Unfortunately, walkers completely escape my coding knowledge. I could really use some help getting it working. Here's the features I need:

- Wrap the second-level `<ul>` in `<section>`. **[COMPLETE]**
- When a user sets the class "break" on an `<li>` in the second level `<ul>`, make that `<li>` the start a new `<ul>`. If it's the first `<li>` in the list, don't do anything, to prevent the formation of empty unordered lists. **[COMPLETE]**
- When a user sets the class "widget" on an `<li>` in the first level that has a sub `<ul>`, append a widget to the end of that `<ul>`. **[COMPLETE]**
- Add class `mega-menu-columns-#` to first level `<li>` elements that contain drop downs with multiple columns and/or a widget. The # represents the number of `<ul>` elements, +1 for the widget if it exists. **[COMPLETE]**

I have a bit of code to do some of this, but not all of it. There are cut-out sections below:

Wrap second level `<ul>` in `<section>`:

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    if ($depth == 0) {
        $output .= "<section>";
    }
    $output .= "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
}
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "</ul>";
    if ($depth == 0) {
        $output .= "</section>\n";
    }
}
```

Generate the widget HTML:

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar("Navigation Callout");
$widget = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

The output HTML would be:

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1 mega-menu-columns-2">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/about/">
            About Us
        </a>
        <section>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/company-profile/">
                        Company Profile
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/">
                        Leadership Team
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/professional-affiliations/">
                        Professional Affiliations
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-5" class="break menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/clients/">
                        Clients
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/partnerships/">
                        Partnerships
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-7" class="widget menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-7 mega-menu-columns-3">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/services/">
            Services
        </a>
        <section>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/services/civil-engineering/">
                        Civil Engineering
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/services/land-planning/">
                        Land Planning
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/services/surveying/">
                        Surveying
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-11" class="break menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/services/information-technology/">
                        Information Technology
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/services/subsurface-utility-engineering/">
                        Subsurface Utility Engineering
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <aside>
                <h6>Widget Title</h6>
                <p>Maecenas quis semper arcu. Quisque consequat risus nisi. Sed venenatis urna porta eros malesuada euismod. Nulla sollicitudin fringilla posuere. Nulla et tellus eu nisi sodales convallis non vel tellus.</p>
            </aside>
        </section>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/contact/">
            Contact Us
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:** My counters are giving me grief. They're only counting after the sub menu's been generated, which doesn't help me. See this screenshot to understand what I mean:

[image]

The top numbers are being pulled in `start_el`. The bottom numbers are being pulled in `end_el`. As you can see, the top numbers aren't counting my `.breaks` as they should. They count the widget class because those are being counted in `$depth = 0`. Someone please save me from this horribleness!

```
// mega menu walker
/*
    ONE REMAINING BUG:
    - Need to add class to LI containing mega-menu-columns-#
*/
class megaMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    private $column_limit = 3; /* needs to be set for each site */
    private $show_widget = false;
    private $column_count = 0;
    static $li_count = 0;
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $item_id = $item->ID;
        if ($depth == 0) self::$li_count = 0;
        if ($depth == 0 && in_array("widget", $classes)) {
            $this->show_widget = true;
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        if ($depth == 1 && self::$li_count == 1) {
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        if ($depth == 1 && in_array("break", $classes) && self::$li_count != 1 && $this->column_count < $this->column_limit) {
            $output .= "</ul><ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        if ($depth == 0 && $this->column_count > 0) {
            $mega_menu_class = " mega-menu-columns-" . $this->column_count;
        }
        $class_names = join(" ", apply_filters("nav_menu_css_class", array_filter($classes), $item));
        $class_names = " class=\"" . esc_attr($class_names . $mega_menu_class) . "\"";
        $output .= sprintf(
            "<li id=\"menu-item-%s\"%s><a href=\"%s\">%s</a>",
            $item_id,
            $class_names,
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
        self::$li_count++;
    }
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "<section>";
        }
        $output .= "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= "</ul>";
        if ($depth == 0) {
            if ($this->show_widget) {
                ob_start();
                dynamic_sidebar("Navigation Callout");
                $widget = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $output .= $widget;
                $this->show_widget = false;
            }
            $output .= "</section>";
        }
    }
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if ($depth == 0 && $this->column_count > 0) {
            /* needs to be added to opening level 0 li */
            $column_count_class = " mega-menu-columns-" . $this->column_count;
            $output .= $column_count_class;
            /* end */
            $this->column_count = 0;
        }
        $output .= "</li>";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Here's an example of output with comments describing how the `mega-menu-columns-` class should count things:

```
<ul>
    <!-- +1 because this has a class of "widget" -->
    <li id="menu-item-1" class="widget menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1 mega-menu-columns-3">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/about/">
            About Us
        </a>
        <!-- +1 because a drop down exists -->
        <!-- gets added by my walker -->
        <section>
        <!-- end gets added by my walker -->
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <!-- +0 because this "break" is the first child -->
                <li id="menu-item-2" class="break menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/company-profile/">
                        Company Profile
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- +0 because this "break" is in level 2 -->
                        <li id="menu-item-3" class="break menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3">
                            <a href="http://www.example.com/about/our-team/">
                                Our Team
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/">
                        Leadership Team
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/professional-affiliations/">
                        Professional Affiliations
                    </a>
                </li>
            <!-- gets added by my walker -->
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <!-- end gets added by my walker -->
                <!-- +1 because this "break" is in level 1 and not the first child -->
                <li id="menu-item-6" class="break menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/clients/">
                        Clients
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/about/partnerships/">
                        Partnerships
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- gets added by my walker for .widget -->
            <section>
                <header>
                    <h1>Widget Title</h1>
                </header>
                <p>This is a widget. It was hard to make appear!</p>
            </section>
            <!-- end gets added by my walker for .widget -->
        <!-- gets added by my walker -->
        </section>
        <!-- end gets added by my walker -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:** Here's my final Walker and Functions. This does *exactly* what I wanted it to. Thanks for the help!

```
// mega menu walker
class megaMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    private $column_limit = 3;
    private $show_widget = false;
    private $column_count = 0;
    static $li_count = 0;
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $item_id = $item->ID;
        if ($depth == 0) {
            self::$li_count = 0;
        }
        if ($depth == 0 && in_array("widget", $classes)) {
            $this->show_widget = true;
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        if ($depth == 1 && self::$li_count == 1) {
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        if ($depth == 1 && in_array("break", $classes) && self::$li_count != 1 && $this->column_count < $this->column_limit) {
            $output .= "</ul><ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
            $this->column_count++;
        }
        $class_names = join(" ", apply_filters("nav_menu_css_class", array_filter($classes), $item)); // set up the classes array to be added as classes to each li
        $class_names = " class=\"" . esc_attr($class_names) . "\"";
        $output .= sprintf(
            "<li id=\"menu-item-%s\"%s><a href=\"%s\">%s</a>",
            $item_id,
            $class_names,
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
        self::$li_count++;
    }
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "<section>";
        }
        $output .= "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= "</ul>";
        if ($depth == 0) {
            if ($this->show_widget) {
                ob_start();
                dynamic_sidebar("Navigation Callout");
                $widget = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $output .= $widget;
                $this->show_widget = false;
            }
            $output .= "</section>";
        }
    }
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if ($depth == 0 && $this->column_count > 0) {
            $this->column_count = 0;
        }
        $output .= "</li>";
    }
}

// add mega-menu-columns-# classes
function add_column_number($items, $args) {
    static $column_limit = 3;
    static $post_id = 0;
    static $x_key = 0;
    static $column_count = 0;
    static $li_count = 0;
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($items as $key => $item) {
        if (0 == $item->menu_item_parent) {
            $x_key = $key;
            $post_id = $item->ID;
            $column_count = 0;
            $li_count = 0;
            if (in_array("widget", $item->classes, 1)) {
                $column_count++;
            }
        }
        if ($post_id == $item->menu_item_parent) {
            $li_count++;
            if ($column_count < $column_limit && $li_count == 1) {
                $column_count++;
            }
            if (in_array("break", $item->classes, 1) && $li_count > 1 && $column_count < $column_limit) {
                $column_count++;
            }
            $tmp[$x_key] = $column_count;
        }
    }
    foreach($tmp as $key => $value) {
        $items[$key]->classes[] = sprintf("mega-menu-columns-%d", $value);
    }
    unset($tmp);
    return $items;
};

// add the column classes
add_filter("wp_nav_menu_args", function($args) {
    if ($args["walker"] instanceof megaMenuWalker) {
        add_filter("wp_nav_menu_objects", "add_column_number");
    }
    return $args;
});

// stop the column classes function
add_filter("wp_nav_menu", function( $nav_menu ) {
    remove_filter("wp_nav_menu_objects", "add_column_number");
    return $nav_menu;
});
```

Comment: This is super amazing and exactly what I have been wanting to build for a long time!  I was not sure how to handle the creation of new columns and such so I really love the idea of just setting a class name on items to create new columns and also the ability to add widget areas, just genius! I am however having some trouble with your finished code...it outputs the corrects HTML however I am getting this PHP error...  `Warning: Missing argument 2 for add_column_number()`  Did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I don't think so, it seems to be working fine on the two sites I've used it on so far. I've updated the above code, in case I changed something when implementing it. Try it again and let me know if it still doesn't work; I'm not very good with PHP but I'd be happy to try and help :)

Comment: What I had to do was change this `function add_column_number($items, $args) {` into this `function add_column_number($items) {` removing the `$args` and it works fine for me with that change, pretty strange!  THanks for sharing your code though it is just what I have needed for a long time

Comment: No problem, I know how difficult it is to do this, which is why I shared my full code :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the problem setup correctly, you could try to do the *break* and *widget* class counting  within the `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter.

Here's an updated example, it's rather expanded because of the extra debug part:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 
    function( $items, $args  ) {

        // Only apply this for the 'primary' menu:    
        if( 'primary' !== $args->theme_location ) 
            return $items;

        // Here "x_" means the latest root li (depth 0)
        static $x_pid           = 0;      // post ID of the latest root li (depth 0) 
        static $x_key           = 0;      // array key of the latest root li (depth 0)
        static $x_cols          = 0;      // n breaks or widgets gives n+1 columns  
        static $x_has_dropdown  = false;  // if the latest root li (depth 0) has dropdown

        // Internals:
        $tmp            = array();  
        $debug_string   = '';
        $show_debug     = true;  // Edit this to your needs:

        foreach( $items as $key => $item )
        {
            // Debug:
            $debug                              = array();
            $debug['ID']                        = $item->ID;
            $debug['title']                     = $item->title;
            $debug['key']                       = $key;
            $debug['x_key']                     = $x_key;
            $debug['depth']                     = '';
            $debug['menu_item_parent']          = $item->menu_item_parent;
            $debug['has_widget_class']          = 0;
            $debug['is_depth_1_first_child']    = 0;
            $debug['x_has_dropdown']            = 0;
            $debug['has_break_class']           = 0;
            $debug['x_cols_increase']           = 0;

            // Collect columns increaments:
            $inc = 0;

            // Depth 0:
            if( 0 == $item->menu_item_parent )
            {
                $debug['depth'] = 0;

                // Resets:
                $x_key          = $key;
                $x_pid          = $item->ID;                            
                $x_cols         = 0;
                $x_has_dropdown = false;

                // If widget class exists:
                if( in_array( 'widget', $item->classes, 1 ) )
                {
                    $debug['has_widget_class'] = '1';
                    $inc++; 
                }       
            }

            // Depth 1:
            if( $x_pid == $item->menu_item_parent )
            {   
                $debug['depth'] = 1;

                // Increase the columns count for an existing dropdown:
                if( ! $x_has_dropdown )
                {
                    $inc++;
                    $x_has_dropdown = true;
                }

                // Check for the 'break' class: 
                if( in_array( 'break', $item->classes, 1 ) )
                {
                    $debug['x_has_break_class'] = 1;

                    // First li child:
                    if( $x_key+1 == $key+0 )
                    {
                        $debug['is_depth_1_first_child'] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $debug['is_depth_1_first_child'] = 0;
                        $inc++; 
                    }
                }

                $t[$x_key] = $x_cols;
            }           

            $debug['x_has_dropdown'] = (int) $x_has_dropdown;

            // Increase the columns count:
            $debug['x_cols_increase'] = $inc;           
            $x_cols += $inc;
            $debug['x_cols'] = $x_cols;

            // Collect the debug:
            $debug_string .= print_r( $debug, 1 );
        } // end foreach

        // Show debug info:
        if( $show_debug ) 
            printf( "<!-- debug: %s -->", $debug_string );

        // Insert the new 'mega menu' class to the corresponding menu object:
        foreach( $t as $key => $value )
        {
            $items[$key]->classes[] = sprintf( 'mega-menu-columns-%d', $value );
        }

        return $items;

    }
, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

With your current menu tree, I get this debug information:

```
<!-- debug: Array
(
    [ID] => 3316
    [title] => About Us
    [key] => 1
    [x_key] => 0
    [depth] => 0
    [menu_item_parent] => 0
    [has_widget_class] => 1
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 0
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 1
    [x_cols] => 1
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3317
    [title] => Company Profile
    [key] => 2
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 1
    [menu_item_parent] => 3316
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 1
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 1
    [x_has_break_class] => 1
    [x_cols] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3318
    [title] => Our Team
    [key] => 3
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 
    [menu_item_parent] => 3317
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 0
    [x_cols] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3319
    [title] => Leadership Team
    [key] => 4
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 1
    [menu_item_parent] => 3316
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 0
    [x_cols] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3320
    [title] => Professional Affiliations
    [key] => 5
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 1
    [menu_item_parent] => 3316
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 0
    [x_cols] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3321
    [title] => Clients
    [key] => 6
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 1
    [menu_item_parent] => 3316
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 1
    [x_has_break_class] => 1
    [x_cols] => 3
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3322
    [title] => Partnerships
    [key] => 7
    [x_key] => 1
    [depth] => 1
    [menu_item_parent] => 3316
    [has_widget_class] => 0
    [is_depth_1_first_child] => 0
    [x_has_dropdown] => 1
    [has_break_class] => 0
    [x_cols_increase] => 0
    [x_cols] => 3
)
 -->
```

If you want to check if the walker object is of the `megaMenuWalker` class, you can use:

```
if( ! is_object( $args->walker ) || ! is_a( $args->walker, 'megaMenuWalker' ) )
    return $items;
```

instead of

```
if( 'primary' !== $args->theme_location ) 
            return $items;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Strangely this is outputting 1 as the number. See http://hfracquetandfitness.myweblinx.net/ (inspect the first li in the top navigation). EDIT -- I think I know why. Break gets added to direct child `<li>` elements, not the current `<li>`. It needs to check that it's a direct child, and not the first child that has the class of `break` as well.

Comment: I updated the answer, I had a typo (&& instead of ||).

Comment: Ah, that helped a bit, but I see it's counting if the current list item has the class of `break`. It actually needs to count if direct children have the class of `break`, not itself, and exclude the first child `li` in the child `ul`, if that makes sense.

Comment: I assume the root `<li>` items are at depth `0`, and then I count the   break/widget classes of the sub `<li>` items at depth `1`. I think I should start the `$x_cols` at `1` instead of `0`, since `n` breaks gives `n+1` columns.

Comment: Yea, as in my walker, if it has any children at all, it should start out at 1. See my updated question for a more clear description (in ~2 minutes).

Comment: I wont' be able to fully test until Monday (I forgot to write down the WP login before I left work), but this appears that it'll count the first child `li` in the list if it has a class of break`. I need to exclude that one. Is this possible?

Comment: I was able to reset the password, this is definitely counting the first `li` in the list if it has a class of `break`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Actually I was able to figure that stuff out. Is there a way to add this to the Walker, or fire it when the walker fires though? I'd prefer to only have to configure one thing when I'm setting this up on sites, rather than two. If not, I can deal with it.

Comment: ok good. I just updated the answer, with some extra debug stuff to help you navigate through this. Hopefully we're getting closer. Maybe there's a way to do this in the walker, but I would have to think more about that ;-) Instead of activating this for the primary menu, we could use something else to trigger it, for example the menu title or a substring in the menu title or whatever you fancy ;-)

Comment: I've posted my final code above. Ideally it should fire whenever the walker fires, but oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with an example how you can check the walker class instead of the theme location. Best of luck with your project.